# GStreamer multicast UDP Streaming not working without 'sprop-parameter-sets' caps set in the client

Tags: streaming, gstreamer, multicast

I need some assistance on this guys.

I am using GStreamer 1.0 (14.2) to capture and stream the PC screen (Windows 10) over udp and receive it on Ubuntu 12.4 client. Updating the Ubuntu is not an option.

Server:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v gdiscreencapsrc ! queue ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! decodebin ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! \
       openh264enc bitrate=3000000 ! \
             h264parse ! video/x-h264 ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=1 \
       ! udpsink host=224.1.1.1 port=5000 auto-multicast=true sync=false
```

Client:

```
gst-launch -v udpsrc port=5000 multicast-group=224.1.1.1 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, packetization-mode=(string)1, profile-level-id=(string)42c029, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z0LAKYyNQDwBEvLAPCIRqA\=\=\,aM48gA\=\=\", payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! queue ! vaapidecode ! vaapisink sync=false
```

If I get the 'sprop-parameter-sets' from the server output and add it to the client's udpsrc caps, everything is ok. The problems start when I try to stream from another PC with the same script and the same GStreamer version. The 'sprop-parameter-sets' do not match and I see only a grey screen.

I have tried without setting the 'sprop-parameter-sets' and it worked, but only if I start the client before the server. Otherwise, the client receives EOS right after it had been launched and shuts down. Setting the 'sprop-parameter-sets' fixed that issue but brought another.

Any help would be appreciated!

P.S Clients are running on Intel® Desktop Board DN2800MT Innovation Series.

Answer (score 0):

`sprop-parameter-sets` should not be required. You should send SPS and PPS inband. You are already trying to do that for `rtph264pay` via the `config-interval=1` option already. Perhaps you need to add it to the `h264parse` as well so it does not filter out any SPS/PPS.

You may want to check on the wire whether you can detect SPS and PPS NAL units being send.

EDIT: Just noticed - it should be `config-interval=-1` so they get inserted before every IDR frame.

Comment: I have added config-interval=-1 to both h264parse and rtph264pay elements on the server and config-interval=1 (in 0.10 it is guint parameter) to h264parse element on the client, but there was no effect. I am attaching the log from the client.
[Client Log](https://pastebin.com/R31mvCnZ)

Comment: I think you need to figure out where the EOS comes from. Since you don't stop the sender I see no reason why it is there. Perhaps the vaapi decoder chokes because you tune in into random access - not having a clean start. Perhaps try `vaapih264dec` directly? It should wait and discard data unless you get a SPS/PPS to decode a picture. Really.. the EOS just doesn't seem right.

Comment: I also noticed there is some problem with the vaapidecode element.
[Vaapidecode Log](https://pastebin.com/hxn4pqqn)
You can see the *decode error 2*, which if I am right should be translated to *GST_VAAPI_DECODER_STATUS_ERROR_ALLOCATION_FAILED*

P.S For some reason I have no `vaapih264dec`. Could you provide me the plugin name and package, maybe a gst-inspect for this element? Thanks.

Comment: On my regular system I just do `gst-inspect-1.0 vaapi` and get all decoder flavors. It may be different on your special board though. I would try to get a software decoder like `avdec_h264` and see if the behavior is the same.

Comment: Also there are GStreamer elements available for the Intel Media SDK. These may worth investigating - they communicate with intel's SDK/hardware directly without the VAAPI layer.